# SubSonic 3 Compatiblity Problem with Not Autogenerated Collections?

Tags: collections, subsonic, subsonic3

Had a system with v2 running well. Swapped out the Visual Studio reference for the v2 DLL to the v3 DLL. Rebuilt the project. Errors.

I used to have things called "MyYahooCollection", now I only have "MyYahoo" and "MyYahooTable". The collections seem to be gone.

What did I miss?

I am using SQL Server 2005 on the back-end and am implementing ActiveRecord.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v3.x isn't entirely backward compatible with v2.x. The collection classes aren't really needed any more. v3.x uses List instead of *Collection (the old v2 *Collection classes derived from this already).

Comment: Yikes. I ran into a licensing problem with v2 of SubSonic (somestuff in the Sugar space) and wanted to implement v3 because it didn't have the same issues. So it sounds like I can't simply rebind and then use....

Can you show a quick snippet (or URL-link) of "how it used to be" vs "how it is now"? All I was doing was finding rows that met a certain string, deleting them, and then inserting some new ones.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't. Did you check out the subsonic post's on Rob's blog? They cover most of that type of stuff blog.wekeroad.com

Comment: What's the licensing problem??

Comment: Mihai Bazon's calendar script is embedded in v2, which is LGPL. v3 does not have this baked in. An employer's source scan flagged this, so it's got to go. Legal stuff, but the bottom line is I have to figure out how to get this out fast or replace SubSonic completely with LINQ-to-SQL (eeew).

Answer (score 4):

Subsonic 3 is NOT compatible with Subsonic 2. If you've got a Subsonic 2.x project, you can't "just" upgrade it. It will not work. Rob described that tradeoff pretty early in the alpha phase of 3.x.

Because 3.x uses LINQ for much of the overall approach and moves away from the *Collection objects toward more IEnumerable and List objects, it requires a much bigger refactoring to use it to replace a 2.x implementation.